# after writing to a file, .read() is printing strange results

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm learning Python as a first language, my study book says to add code that reads the newly written file, however whenever I try a `print target.read()` the script runs but when it is supposed to output on the 4th line from last, it outputs strange unreadable characters.

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

print "We're going to erase %r." % filename
print "If you wish to cancel, press CTRL-C."
print "To continue, press RETURN."

raw_input(">")

print "Opening the file..."
target = open(filename, 'w+')   

print "Truncating the file. Bye!"
target.truncate()

print "Now I'm going to ask you for three lines."

line1 = raw_input("Line 1: ")
line2 = raw_input("Line 2: ")
line3 = raw_input("Line 3: ")

print "These will be wrote to the file."

target.write(line1)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line2)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line3)
target.write("\n")

print "The text in this file reads as: \n "
print target.read()
print "And finally, we close it."
target.close
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read()` starts reading from the current position in the file. After all the `write()` calls, the current position is after the last byte that was written. You need to go back to the beginning of the file to read what you just wrote:

```
target.seek(0)
print "The texxt in this file reads as: \n"
print target.read()
```

BTW, you don't need to use `target.truncate()`. When you open a file in `w` or `w+` mode, it's automatically truncated.

And `target.close` doesn't do anything. You need parentheses to call the function, so it should be `target.close()`. But it would be better style to use `with` so the file is closed automatically.

Comment: also `target.close` does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Close the file & open it for reading before, uh, reading from it.

Answer (score 0):

Change print target.read()`with

```
with open("example_txt.txt") as xx:
    print xx.read()

target.close ---> target.close()
```

Comment: If you're going to open a separate stream to read, you need to flush or close the writing stream first.

Comment: But I think his whole point was to use the same stream for reading and writing, that's why he used `w+` mode when opening it.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

As stated earlier, the w+ already starts at the beginning of the file, so your truncate() is unnecessary. Also, you aren't reading the whole file object when you do the read() since the target is on the last line which is just an /n character. If you open the txt file after, you will see your three lines and an empty line at the end from your last /n you wrote.

Typically I would think it's better practice to either build your file you want to write in memory and write the entire thing so you can check it before writing. Otherwise write incrementally, close it and re-open it for reading.

Lastly you should use the following syntax for opening files so they automatically close:

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

print "We're going to erase %r." % filename
print "If you wish to cancel, press CTRL-C."
print "To continue, press RETURN."

raw_input(">")

print "Now I'm going to ask you for three lines."
line1 = raw_input("Line 1: ")
line2 = raw_input("Line 2: ")
line3 = raw_input("Line 3: ")

print "Opening the file..."
with open(filename, 'w+') as f:
    print "These will be written to the file."
    f.write(line1 + '\n')
    f.write(line2 + '\n')
    f.write(line3 + '\n')
    print "The file will close automatically after this line."

print "The text in this file reads as: \n "
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    print f.read()
```

There are many other ways to do this even simpler, but this is a good alternative. If you follow along, you'll see we build our text for input, then we write each line while the file is open and it automatically closes after it leaves the 'with' block. Then we can open it safely read-only for printing the contents. We could have also appended your lines together into a single variable, printed it before writing anything to make sure it's right, and then write the entire object as one piece.

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

print "We're going to erase %r." % filename
print "If you wish to cancel, press CTRL-C."
print "To continue, press RETURN."

raw_input(">")

print "Now I'm going to ask you for three lines."
line1 = raw_input("Line 1: ")
line2 = raw_input("Line 2: ")
line3 = raw_input("Line 3: ")

contents = line1 + '\n' + line2 + '\n' + line3 + '\n'

print "These will be written to the file.\n"
print contents

print "Opening the file..."
with open(filename, 'w+') as f:
    f.write(contents)
    print "The file will close automatically after this line."
```